# HumHub install by own project composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I want to install HumHub (github.com/humhub/humhub) with my own composer file. But composer do not install humhub dependencies.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
      "name": "my-project",
      "type": "project",
      "repositories": [
        {
          "type": "package",
          "package": {
            "name": "humhub/humhub",
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "source": {
              "url": "https://github.com/humhub/humhub.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference": "master"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "require": {
        "humhub/humhub": "1.1.1"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error messages? Are you trying to get humhub using git, not packagist or so? If you are fetching directly from github, try

```
"repositories": [{ "type": "git", "url": "https://github.com/humhub/humhub.git"}]
```

and leave "require" as you have it now.

EDIT: I just noticed, that there is nothing tagged as "1.1.1" on humhub's repository. You can find a tag "v1.1.1", therefore change your "require" to:

```
"require": {"humhub/humhub": "dev-master#v1.1.1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories), here is how add a git repository as a composer dependency.

I've modified their example to use the humhub library.

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "humhub/humhub": "dev-master#1.1.1"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:humhub/humhub.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the humhub composer installer: https://github.com/move-elevator/humhub-composer-installer